# AFNetworking upload image using AFHTTPClient

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afhttpclient

My question is why `AFHTTPClient` is slow to upload image. I am using the below code for uploading

```
    NSData *imageToUpload = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(uploadedImgView.image, 1.0);
    NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:keyParameter, @"keyName", nil];

    AFHTTPClient *client= [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://------"]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"API name as you have" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData: imageToUpload name:@"image" fileName:@"temp.jpeg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    }];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     {
         NSDictionary *jsons = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:kNilOptions error:nil];
         //NSLog(@"response: %@",jsons);

     }
                                     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {
         if([operation.response statusCode] == 403)
         {
             //NSLog(@"Upload Failed");
             return;
         }
         //NSLog(@"error: %@", [operation error]);

     }];

    [operation start];
```

Comment: AFHTTPClient this is old use AFN3.0 and check

Comment: @Nitin Gohel  actully i'm using restkit so it contains afnetworking 1.0  so while upload image using 1.0 but why this slow, is it?

Comment: check your internet speed might be that cause of internet slow,. By the way how do you predict that upload slow?

Comment: @Nitin Gohel actully uplading 20 kb image, it's takes 2-3 min to upload, is is server issue or afhttpclient (afnetworking 1.0 version ) issue.

Comment: i dont think its AFN issue.

Comment: @Nitin Gohel  as per i think too it's server issue but let's trying me afnetworking 2.0 which i used previously application,it was perfect so

Answer (score 0):

It might be happen that your image is large and taking time to upload Or you can use latest AFNetworking and can track progress while upload image.

```
NSData *imageToUpload = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(uploadedImgView.image, 1.0);
NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:keyParameter, @"keyName", nil];
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];

NSString *URLtoCall = @"API name as you have";

[manager POST:URLtoCall parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData>  _Nonnull formData) {
[formData appendPartWithFileData:imageToUpload name:@"image" fileName:@"temp.jpeg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
   } progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {


   } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

   }];
```

Comment: OP using afn1.0 with rest kit your answer not suitable with OP

Comment: @Rahul Patel no it's approx 20 kb

Comment: @NitinGohel know that's why I mentioned latest AFNetworking mate

Comment: @saurabh : Ok. Try AFN3.0 and check any improvisation.

Comment: ok sir : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37108694/afnetworking-upload-image-afhttpclient?noredirect=1#comment61759355_37108694

Comment: @Rahul Patel Restkit doesn't have afnetworking 3.0 so ?

Comment: @saurabh . I an noit srure

Comment: @ Rahul Patel @Nitin Gohel hi actully that was nsdata issue of conversion from jpeg to png  which is resolve now, neither issue of server nor afnetworking both are correct thanx